# side by side plot using AgroR

Tags: r, ggplot2

I plotted two graph using AgroR function: I try to merge it using ggplot function and grid extra but doesn't work?

I tried ggplot function and Gridextra using the following FUNCTION: `grid.arrange`, `cowplot:gridExtra::grid.arrange`, but  none works

Answer (score 0):

Can you reproduce this example?  From here: [Example of cowplot with side-by-side graphs](https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/plot_grid.html).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + 
  geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, mpg)) +
  geom_point()

plot_grid(p1, p2, labels = c('A', 'B'))
```

What functions in AgroR did you use to create your graphs?

Can you post what you tried?

**UPDATE**

Thank you for showing what you tried.  I don't have your data and so I will try to do a similar plot using the `laranja` data set in `AgroR`.  I just changed the variables in DBC to match the `laranja` variables but I did not change the rest of your code.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(AgroR)

data(laranja)
attach(laranja)

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, mpg)) + geom_point()

p1 <- with(laranja, DBC(trat, bloco, resp, ylab=expression("Days"),xlab="SITE 1", 
          CV=TRUE,addmean=TRUE, textsize=14, labelsize=4.5, angle= 0, width.bar= 0.05,
            width.column= 0.7,sup=0.05, angle.label= 0,norm="sw", 
            mcomp="sk", geom="box", homog="bt", fill= "trat"))
```

Your issue is that `p1` is getting saved as a `list`, not as a graph.  It is a list of only one element (the graph), but you have to call it explicitly.  To do that, you use `p1[[1]]`, which uses element 1 in the `p1` list.

Try this:

```
plot_grid(p1[[1]], p2)
```

[image]

Comment: I have try the cowplot, its not working, here is the code:    plot 1
P1<- with(a,DBC (Trt,Rep,D2T,
               ylab=expression("Days"),xlab="SITE 1",
               CV=TRUE,addmean=TRUE, textsize=14,
               labelsize=4.5, angle= 0, width.bar= 0.05,width.column= 0.7,sup=0.05,
               angle.label= 0,norm="sw", mcomp="sk", geom="box",
               homog="bt", fill= "trat"))

Comment: The code: plot_grid(p1[[1]], p2) works perfectly. Thanks